# Failed assertion: line 61 pos 12: '_route == ModalRoute.of(context)': is not true

Tags: flutter, dart

When i open my app to the login screen, the screen works fine not thing happnes,
Now when i click on the signup button and i try to click on back to login i get this error

```
    ======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown building Form-[LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>#d062b](state: FormState#ba10e):
'package:flutter/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart': Failed assertion: line 61 pos 12: '_route == ModalRoute.of(context)': is not true.


Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
  https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  Form-[LabeledGlobalKey<FormState>#d062b] file:///C:/Users/Dell%20Latitude/AndroidStudioProjects/handyman_client/lib/screens/home_page.dart:61:65
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#2      _WillPopScopeState.didUpdateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/will_pop_scope.dart:61:12)
#3      StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4815:58)
#4      Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#5      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#6      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
...
====================================================================================================

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.
====================================================================================================
```

After looking at it i have seen its coming from my form Widget
Here is my Code:
But please take note of the form widget

```
    import 'package:auto_size_text/auto_size_text.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:handyman_client/models/login_model.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
            child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Image.asset("assests/images/onboarding1.png", width: 80, height: 80,),
                      Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 50),
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            "HANDYMAN",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF2AF219),
                                fontSize: 14,
                                fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                    child: Consumer<LoginModel>(
                      builder: (context, mLoginValue, child) => Form(
                        key: mLoginValue.formKey,
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            AutoSizeText(
                              "Hire skilled handy workers that lives in you area",
                              maxLines: 3,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFF2AF219),
                                  fontSize: 25,
                                  fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w900
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 12,),
                            AutoSizeText(
                              "Sign In",
                              maxLines: 2,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Color(0xFFC4C4C4),
                                  fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                  fontSize: 24
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            AutoSizeText(
                              "Email",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF2AF219),
                                fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                                        offset: Offset(6, 2),
                                        blurRadius: 6.0,
                                        spreadRadius: 3.0
                                    )
                                  ]
                              ),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                validator: (v) => mLoginValue.validateEmail(v),
                                controller: mLoginValue.emailController,
                                keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: "email@mail.com",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFFC4C4C4),
                                      fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                    )
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 12,),
                            AutoSizeText(
                              "Password",
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF2AF219),
                                fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(height: 10,),
                            Container(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0),
                              height: 50,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                        color: Color.fromRGBO(0, 0, 0, 0.1),
                                        offset: Offset(6, 2),
                                        blurRadius: 6.0,
                                        spreadRadius: 3.0
                                    )
                                  ]
                              ),
                              child: TextFormField(
                                controller: mLoginValue.passwordController,
                                validator: (v) => mLoginValue.validatePassword(v),
                                obscureText: true,
                                decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    border: InputBorder.none,
                                    hintText: "password",
                                    hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                      color: Color(0xFFC4C4C4),
                                      fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                    )
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 15,),
                  Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 180),
                    child: FlatButton(
                      onPressed: (){
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/forgotPassword');
                      },
                      child: AutoSizeText(
                        "Forgot Password",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Color(0xFFC4C4C4),
                          fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 20,),
                  Container(
                    child:  Consumer<LoginModel>(
                      builder: (context, mLoginValue, child) => InkWell(
                        onTap: () async {
                          mLoginValue.createLogin();
                          if(mLoginValue.isVerified){
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/profileImageScreen');
                          }
                        },
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 28.93,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        "Don't have account?",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF464444),
                            fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                            fontSize: 11
                        ),
                      ),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: (){
                            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/clientSignUp');
                          },
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            "Click Here",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF2AF219),
                                fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                fontSize: 11,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      AutoSizeText(
                        "For more information visit",
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF464444),
                            fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                            fontSize: 11
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 50,),
                      FlatButton(
                          onPressed: (){},
                          child: AutoSizeText(
                            "www.handyman.com",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF2AF219),
                                fontFamily: 'Ramabhadra',
                                fontSize: 11,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                            ),
                          )
                      )
                    ],
                  )
                ]
            )
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

also i made use of providers
here is the code:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:handyman_client/signUp_Validation/validate.dart';

class LoginModel extends ChangeNotifier with ValidationMixin {
  TextEditingController emailController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController passwordController = TextEditingController();

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String _message = "";
  bool _isVerified = false;

  set message(msg) {
    _message = msg;
    notifyListeners();
  }
  get message {
    return this._message;
  }

  set isVerified(bool verified) {
    _isVerified = verified;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  get isVerified {
    return this._isVerified;
  }

  Future<void> createLogin() {
    if (validateForm()) {
      emailController.text;
      passwordController.text;
      isVerified = true;
    }else {
      message = "Please fill the form";
      isVerified = false;
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }

  bool validateForm() {
    return formKey.currentState.validate();
  }
}
```

Please how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have two widget with same Key
try to change   final formKey = GlobalKey();
to formKey = GlobalKey(); and try to initialize it in widget it self and passet formState to changeNotifier

```dart
class LoginModel extends ChangeNotifier with ValidationMixin {
    /// remove this line 
    final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
    
    //add form key as parameter
    Future<void> createLogin(GlobalKey<FormState> formKey) {
    if (validateForm(formKey)) {
    ///...
    }else {
     
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
  bool validateForm(GlobalKey<FormState> formKey) {
    return formKey.currentState.validate();
  }
}

/// in Home Widget init form key
 GlobalKey<FormState> formKey

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
   formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  }
```

Comment: sorry pls can you explain more or put it in a code form? please

Comment: I update my answer 
and  after reading more you code my advice to you is no need to go with provider to create your form